# Notebook Parameter Issue

Tags: azure-databricks

I have passed the parameter in Notebook 1

%run /Development/Tickets/silver_object_lead_cdf_latest $VarA="source_full_object_name" $VarB="destination_full_object_name"

And I am trying to call the parameter $VarA in notebook 2 with following query :

SELECT * FROM $VarA

But i am getting error :

AnalysisException: Invalid usage of '*' in expression 'alias'.

Please advise.

Regards
Rohit

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when I tried using the same select statement.

[image]

- Make sure that you are using the correct variable name and use query as shown below instead:

```
%sql

select  '$VarA'  as varA
```

[image]

Comment: The "source_full_object_name" is the delta name table. I need to ready all the columns from the respective table how it can be achieved

Comment: Can you give an example of what you are trying to achieve

Comment: The table name i am passing in  $VarA="source_full_object_name" in this parameter in NotebookA abd try to run the delta table in Notebook B. The details is mentioned above

Comment: You can retrieve the value using widgets and use it inside spark.sql to query the table inside notebook which is called.

Comment: I don't want to use widgets

Comment: The value is being sent as a string. There is no `execute` command in azure databricks sql to execute a dynamic query. You might have to use spark.sql() and to use this, you might have to use widgets